# "Error in optim. L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'" In PGLS

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a PGLS analysis using the "caper" package in R but this error appears every time I try to perform the function:

> Error in optim(optimPar, fn = pgls.likelihood, method = "L-BFGS-B", control = control , : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

This is my script:

```
comp.data<-comparative.data(phy=tree.ultra, data=mammalS, 
                            names.col="phylacine_binomial",vcv=F, 
                            vcv.dim=2,na.omit=T)
mammalS <-pgls(bodymass ~ Temp, comp.data, lambda = 'ML', delta = 'ML')
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

I've looked for this error and what I've found is that it may be related to my dataset. However, I've already checked my data for no empty values.

Comment: I agree with your take that it is likely something in the data - naturally, it's challenging for folks to help you troubleshoot without the data. Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(mammalS)`? Good luck!